# Windows Update failure error 80073712

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My computer running Win 7 home 32 bit is facing some issues.

The first s is that Windows Update is not able to check for updates. I get an error 80073712 Unknown error.

I tried most options on [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509997) but to no avail. Actually running `sfc /scannow` gives **Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation"**

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: We won't be able to help until you fix the scf error: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/error-message-windows-resource-protection-could/2e8e994e-08b7-4ccf-859c-685c7bf1614e

Answer (score 3):

Your WinSxS folder is corrupted:

```
C:\Users\Andre>err 80073712
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x3712
# for hex 0x3712 / decimal 14098
  ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT                              winerror.h
# The component store has been corrupted.
# 1 matches found for "80073712"
```

Run the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-is-the-System-Update-Readiness-Tool) and if this tool is unable to fix it, run the [repair installation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: I had no idea there was a command that explained what an error code meant.  I wish I knew this 6 months ago when I encourtered the window error code problem I had.

Comment: I think this is the problem. I already installed the System Update readiness Tool to no avail. I guess I'll have to repair the installation.

Comment: I tried repairing the installation but each time the installation failed, telling me to restart my computer and try again. I did a clean install and obviously this solved the problem.

Comment: ok, put this in the answer and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 already includes a built-in troubleshooting platform that can be accessed from the Control Panel. It contains several [troubleshooting programs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424311%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that can automatically fix some common problems with your computer, such as problems with Windows Update.

You can access Troubleshooting by clicking ...

Control Panel (in Category view) > under System and Security > Find and fix problems > Fix problems with Windows Update

or, Control Panel (in Icon view) > Action Center > Troubleshooting > Fix problems with Windows Update

If your PC does not have this pack installed, you can run or download it from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/).